# WPF to silverlight conversion

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to support `{x:Type}` and `{x:Static}` in silverlight like WPF?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
            <Style.Triggers> 
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Value="{x:Null}"> 
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="test!" /> 
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> 
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers> 
        </Style>
```

Comment: I don't believe DataTriggers are supported in Silverlight.  You could achieve the same thing by creating an IValueConverter that returns a different Style based on the object.